# Changing a for loop to a while loop in Python

Tags: list, loops, for-loop, while-loop

```
myList=[1,2,3,5]
def findMax(aList):
     biggest = aList[0]
     for value in aList: 
           if value > biggest:
               biggest = value
     return biggest
```

This code searches for the largest number in a list.

How would I change this into a while loop, rather than a for loop?

Comment: why do you want that? and y not use max([1,2,3,4,5])?

Comment: It's an assignment in class, to see if we can change from a for loop to while. And I know about the max function, but we can't use that he said. :) I can't figure it out though.

Comment: set a variable (i) to index through the array. the condition for the while loop is i less than the size of the list. Increment i within the loop.

Comment: Consider putting the details from your comment (it is a homework assignment and that you need to solve this problem without a for loop or the max function) so people can understand where you're coming from.

Answer (score 1):

```
myList=[1,2,3,5]
def findMax(aList):
     biggest = aList.pop()
     while(len(aList) > 0):
         element = aList.pop()
         if (element > biggest):
             biggest = element
     return biggest
```

Comment: So each time the while loop runs len shrinks, because of pop?

Comment: Yup. If you don't specify in (), it will remove the last. See [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is declare a simple counter before you go into the loop and then after you check if the value is greater than `biggest`, you add one to the counter. Make sure to check if the counter is equal to the size of the array though, so you don't go out of bounds of it. If it is, you can break out of the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
myList=[1,2,3,5]

def findMax(aList):
     i = 0
     biggest = aList[0]
     while (i < len(myList)):
          if myList[i] > biggest:
               biggest = value
          i += 1;
     return biggest
```

Comment: At least he put some code. ;) If ther eis code, then he deserve some answer

Answer (score 0):

```
myList=[1,2,3,5]
def findMax(aList):
     biggest = aList[0]
     ii = 1
     while ii < len(aList): 
           if aList[ii] > biggest:
               biggest = aList[ii]
           ii += 1
     return biggest
```